# Receiving “(my app name) isn't responding right now. Please try again soon” on Actions on google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Keep receiving “(my app name) isn't responding right now. Please try again soon” on my actions on google simulator, I’ve tried almost all the solution that I found on the internet and ended up with this, I decided to copy the code from google https://developers.google.com/assistant/df-asdk/helpers#calling_the_helper it works just the permission one , for the permission handler it doesn’t work it seems like if I do not put the default response in dialogflow It wouldn’t work so I don’t want that default response because it keeps saying that response, and when I removed it , it gave me an error ,but in the debug tap it shows everything(display name, location etc.)

Comment: Please provide more details. Can you share whole error message? Where you are getting this error? By Simulator you mean Google Assistan Simulator? Please provide your steps, did you use any guide? Please provide some overview, what you except and what you receive now.

Comment: I just found out that the code in the link I posted when I removed the `new Suggestion()` it works. But I really really thank you

Comment: Glad to hear that. Could you elaborate your solution and post it as an answer? It might help other users with similar issue.

Comment: @PjoterS it happened again when I deploy with firebase cloud functions `Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of invalid platform response: Could not find a RichResponse or SystemIntent in the platform response for agentId: .... and intentId: ..... . WebhookStatus: code: 7\nmessage: \"Webhook call failed. Error: PERMISSION_DENIED.\"\n.` can you help me please :(

Comment: According to SO rules, you should provide solution for issue from original question and create another question for issue with firebase cloud function but you need to provide more details for troubleshooting or replication steps.

Comment: @PjoterS maybe this is the first question I asked because when I said the issue has been solved because I just gave up with this and tried express.js instead because ( I found the solution while using this (delete `new Suggestion()` ) ) I don't want to waste the trail for no reason and keep deploying so this maybe ralate to the first question I asked about and the error there is what I got in the first question, same error text

Comment: In that case you need to provide more information. Some overview of your process, environment details, how did you configure google products and firebase, which tutorials you have used (deploying firebase), what you are expecting, etc.
Without those information its hard to troubleshoot or replicate this issue.